# Values not visible when printing list of objects

Tags: python, list

Totally rewritten code:

```
HOR = [0, 1, 3, 6]
VER = [0,10,20,100,1000]

class Pos:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        if (x in HOR) and (y in VER):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
        else:
            print "Invalid position: ", x, y

    def __str__(self):
        return self.x + self.y

    def get_x(self):
        return self.x

    def get_y(self):
        return self.y

class list_A1:
    def __init__(self):  # create a A1 object     
        self.list_A1 = []
        for i in HOR:
            for j in VER:
                self.list_A1.append(Pos(i,j))

    def __str__(self):
        d = "list_A1 contains: " + repr(self)
        return d  # return a string representing the A1

a1 = list_A1()
print a1
```

Now I get:

```
list_A1 contains: <__main__.list_A1 object>
```

but I want to get list of `[x,y]`, for example:

```
[[1,1],[1,2]...]
```

I am new to object programming and I don't understand why I can't see these values in the list.

Comment: try `d = "A1 contains: " + str(self.A)`

Comment: you are confusing `self.A` with `A1`. You should also change `self.A1.append` to `self.A.append` in the `__init__`. You don't possibly want to use `self.A1` if `A1` is your class name.

Comment: I'd also suggest, just for help yourself learning, to rename the `class A1` to something very different, like `class NotTheList` until you've experimented enough and feel confident about what is happening.

Comment: Does your class actually have an `def append` method? It is not posted in your code example.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the name everywhere to "list_A1" and I got this:[<__main__.Pos object>,<__main__.Pos object>,....].

Comment: And does that do what you want? (If not, could you post the updated code example and explain the expected result?)

Comment: aha, that's because `class Pos` also needs a `def __str__` function just like the class in the example. However the bigger problem is that now you named both your list and class `list_A1`. What I tried to tell that these are two separate object: `class list_A1` has nothing to do with `self.list_A1`, these are two *completely different* things (objects). Could you add the code where you print it, along with the part where you make the variable (instance) out of the class?

Comment: OK I changed code but result is not this which I expected...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do

```
self.A.append(Pos(x,y))
```

instead of

```
self.A1.append(Pos(x,y))
```

and

```
d = "A1 contains: " + str(self.A)
```

**Edit:**

Implement `str(self)` and `repr(self)` of `Pos` if you want to print them.

Comment: Thanks. I corrected this typo but the problem still exists. There is the same TypeError and the same line.

Comment: Note that it is `str(self.A)`, *not*  `str(self.A())`.

Comment: It helped, but now it prints out: A1 contains: [<__main__.Pos object>,....] but I intented to get list of [x,y], for example [[1,1],[1,2]...]

Comment: OK. I edited my code but unfortunately, the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The parentheses after `self.A1` mean that you are trying to call it as if it were a function. As the error message tells you, you cannot call a list. The correct syntax would be:

```
d = "A1 contains: " + str(self.A1)
```

or, better

```
d = "A1 contains: {}".format(self.A1)
```

Also, you seem to be using `A1` (the class name) and `A` (the instance attribute) interchangeably; you should give your classes, attributes and methods more sensible and meaningful names to help avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`A1.A1` is not defined in your code example. If it is a list, just change the line to:

```
d = "A1 contains: " + str(self.A1)
```